# Render number of days instead of a date in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, django-models

I’m building a simple blog in Django about a newborn baby.  For blog posts' dates, rather than just grabbing a date from the db rendering “Posted on {{post.created|date}}”  I want to do something like “X days old”  where X = postCreated - birthDate.  Does this need to be done in the model or can this be done in the template itself?

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from datetime import datetime, date

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog.views.post', args=[self.slug]
```

Here is my view:

```
def post (request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {'post':post})
```

And here is my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{post.title}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
            <p>
                Posted on <time datetime="{{post.created|date:"c"}}">{{post.created|date}}</time> 
            </p>
        </header>
        <p class="description">
            {{post.description}}
        </p>
        {{post.content|safe}}
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If timesince doesn't have all you need, [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is pretty nice and will keep updating while the page is open.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in template using [`timesince`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) filter.

Update your template to use below code wherever required.

```
{{post.created|timesince}}
```

From the docs:

> timesince: Formats a date as the time since that date (e.g., “4 days, 6
>   hours”).

Comment: I just got around to implementing this and I'm not sure TimeSince is the right method.  Sample use cases:

*Desired Result*

Birthdate = ’2013-12-11’
PostCreated = ‘2013-12-13’
DaysOld = PostCreated - Birthdate
DaysOld = 2

Birthdate = ’2013-12-11’
PostCreated = ‘2013-12-21’
DaysOld = PostCreated - Birthdate
DaysOld = 10

Using ‘timesince’ is taking the difference from Today and PostCreated:

Birthdate = ’2013-12-11’
PostCreated = ‘2013-12-13’
Timesince = Today - PostCreated
DaysOld = 53 days

Birthdate = ’2013-12-11’
PostCreated = ‘2014-2-1’
Timesince = Today - PostCreated
DaysOld = 1

Comment: @James, If you read the doc of `timesince`, it can take date to compare with e.g. `{{post.created|timesince:birthdate}}`